# getting ID of activerecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Current Code

```
@current_site_name = 'SITENAME'
@current_site = Site.where(:name => @current_site_name)
@current_site_id = @current_site.id
```

Basically, the `name` column in our `Site` model is unique. We are selecting a row using the site name as a parameter.

I am returned: `<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x59426bc1>`

I understand that I cannot simply ask for `@current_site.id` but is there any way to put the ID of the single activerecord into the variable `@current_site_id`

Again, there will always be one active record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've seen, `where` will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` (a set of rows), even if there's only one row that matches your criteria. You can make `@current_site` be assigned to the row you want by changing the line to this:

```
@current_site = Site.where(:name => @current_site_name).first
```

Comment: I thought I tried this but I believe I had `.first!` -- bleh, its always simple. Thanks.

Comment: This is definitely simpler than my approach

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... This is quite strange.

```
Site.where(:name => @current_site_name).methods.include? :id #=> false
```

but

```
Site.where(:name => @current_site_name).instance_methods.include? :id #=> true
```

However,

```
Site.where(:name => @current_site_name).instance_eval "id" #=> NameError
```

and

```
Site.where(:name => @current_site_name).methods.include? "self.id" #=> NoMethodError
```

That said, a workaround assuming in your case, only one record should be returned is

```
Site.where(:name => @current_site_name).instance_eval('find_first').id
```

The `find_first` method is `protected` so we have to jump scope in its execution to avoid another `NoMethodError`

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw another solution out there, you can make use of Rails' [dynamic finders](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders) that are created for your models.

```
@current_site = Site.find_by_name(@current_site_name)
```

This returns a single record (and thus doesn't require the use of `first`) and might be seen as cleaner code in some people's opinion.